# background-color doesn't work when using flexbox

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I started using flexbox for my footers and now on all of my pages with forms the background-color is now the default white.  Here is an example of one of my pages:

login.php

```css
body {
    background-color: #211e1e;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 95vh;
}

h1 {
    color: #99cc00;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    color: #99cc00;
    font-size: 10px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

h3 {
    position: absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #99cc00;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 91.5%;

}

.button {
    background-color: #211e1e;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    /*padding: 15px 50px;*/
    transition-duration: .4s;
    border: greenyellow;
    width: 250px;
    /* width of button */
    height: 50px;
    /* height of button */
}

.buttonColor:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 25%;
}

content {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.signin {
    color: #99cc00;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.loginInput {
    font-size: 24px;
}

.loginButton {
    background-color: #211e1e;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    transition-duration: .4s;
    border: greenyellow;
}

.loginButtonColor:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TapLovers</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../background.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class=content>
        <h1><img src="../../36x36-icon.png">apLovers</h1>
        <form class="signin">
            <input type="text" email="email" placeholder="Email" class="loginInput"><br>
            <input type="text" password="password" placeholder="Password" class="loginInput"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="login" class="loginButton loginButtonColor" value="Login To TapLovers!" /><br><br>
            <a href="../register/register.php">
                <font color="#99cc00">Create a FREE TapLovers Account!</font>
            </a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <h3><img src="../../favicon.ico">apLovers</h3><br>&copy 2018 TapLovers, All Rights Reserved
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Also I was trying to center my forms and my title using flexbox as well and I haven't gotten that working either.  I'm not really sure what other details would be useful for this particular problem.  If you need any more details just reply below and I'll answer them as they come out.

EDIT: The snippet that compiles on stack overflow shows my background just fine.  What's more is if I use ctrl+shift+i on my page then the background works but if I just reload on my page then the background will turn white.

Comment: If your example on Stackoverflow works like expecting, it will be hard for people to help you resolve your original issue

Answer (score 0):

I did not see the issue with background fluctuations. I think it is a delay in the page load. I have added comments to help with the flexbox centering of items.

```css
/*CSS reset of browser agent. Removes the horizontal scroll currently happening in page.*/

* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

body {
 background-color: #211e1e;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
    /* No need to restrict the height.
 height: 95vh;*/
}
h1 {
 color: #99cc00;
 text-align: center;
}

.content {
 flex: 1 0 auto;
 /*make the content div flex so that the form can take the center alignment from flexbox properties. Add the centering here and avoid the margin: auto property */
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #99cc00;
 font-size: 10px;
 flex-shrink: 0;
}

h3 {
 position: absolute;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #99cc00;
 font-size: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 top: 91.5%;
}

.button {
 background-color: #211e1e;
 color: white;
 font-size: 24px;
 /*padding: 15px 50px;*/
 transition-duration: .4s;
 border: greenyellow;
 width: 250px;
 /* width of button */
 height: 50px;
 /* height of button */
}
.buttonColor:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: greenyellow;
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 bottom: 25%;
}

/*Add flexbox style the inputs as blocks and remove <br> from HTML*/

.signin {
 color: #99cc00;
 font-size: 24px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.signin>* {
 margin: 5px 0;
}

.loginInput {
 font-size: 24px;
}

.loginButton {
 background-color: #211e1e;
 color: white;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 10px 50px;
 /*Please check your animation ??
    transition-duration: .4s;*/
 /*add border size and transparency 1px solid*/
 border: 1px solid greenyellow;
}

.loginButtonColor:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
 <h1><img src="../../36x36-icon.png">apLovers</h1>
 <form class="signin">
  <input class="loginInput" placeholder="Email" type="text"> <input class="loginInput" placeholder="Password" type="text"> <input class="loginButton loginButtonColor" id="login" name="submit" type="submit" value="Login To TapLovers!"> <a href="../register/register.php"><font color="#99CC00">Create a FREE TapLovers Account!</font></a>
 </form>
</div>
<footer>
 <h3><img src="../../favicon.ico">apLovers</h3>
 <p>&copy; 2018 TapLovers, All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: In the example you made my footer ends up being being right under my form instead of the bottom of the page.  The reason I put in that height restriction was to set my container to that and then put my footer under the container.  Is there a way for me to have a footer stuck at the bottom without that?

Comment: I understand let me adjust that

Comment: Does the app take up the full screen view?

Comment: Yes, It's full screen.  It's a webpage.